# How to load a txt file one by one in R rather than read all at once and combine into a single matrix

Tags: r

I have 100 text file in a folder. I can use this function below to read all the files and store it into myfile.

```
file_list <- list.files("C:/Users/User/Desktop/code/Test/", full=T)
file_con <- lapply(file_list, function(x){
return(read.table(x, head=F, quote = "\"", skip = 6, sep = ","))
})
myfile <- do.call(rbind, file_con)
```

My question is how I can read the first file in the Test folder before I read the second file. All the text file name also are different and I cannot change it to for example number from 1 to 100. I was thinking of maybe can add a integer no infront of all my text file, then use a for loop to match the file and call but is this possible?

I need to read the first file then do some calculation and then export the result into result.txt before read the second file.but now I'm doing it manually and I have almost 800 file, so it will be a big trouble for me to sit and wait it to compute. The code below is the one that I current in use.

```
myfile = read.table("C:/Users/User/Desktop/code/Test/20081209014205.txt", header = FALSE, quote = "\"", skip = 0, sep = ",")
```

Comment: What is the problem in reading the files from the list that you have `file_list` one by one.

Comment: You might want to perform calculation and write.table in the function

Comment: @AaghazHussain my problem is if I use the file_list, I do not know that data belong to which original file because all the file_list was combine into a matrix myfile

Comment: @chinsoon12 my code work in the way that first I will load the file then the calculation will be done in another while loop (all calculation formula is in my while loop. So may I know exactly the idea that you have in your comment?

Comment: @Alex Can you please tell what calculation is required to be done with the text file?

Comment: @KunalPuri Distance calculation based on the points value from the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following setup will read one file at the time, perform an analysis,
and save it back with a slightly modified name.

```
save_file_list <- structure(
    .Data = gsub(
        pattern = "\\.txt$",
        replacement = "-e.txt",
        x = file_list),
    .Names = file_list)


your_function <- function(.file_content) {
    ##  The analysis you want to do on the content of each file.
}

for (.file in file_list) {
    .file_content <- read.table(
        file = .file,
        head = FALSE,
        quote = "\"",
        skip = 6,
        sep = ",")
    .result <- your_function(.file_content)
    write.table(
        x = .result,
        file = save_file_list[.file])
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lars, I finally figure it out how to use it in my case. Just as you explain above. I just have to put my function in the for loop and then change the format of the save file.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can read a file and do calculation using

```
for(e in 1:100){ 
myfile = read.table(file_list[e], header = FALSE, quote = "\"", skip = 0, sep = ",");
while(condition){
 Calculation
}
myresult <- file.path("C:/Users/User/Desktop/code/Result/", paste0("-",e, ".txt"));
write.table(x, file = myresult, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE ,sep = ",");
```

Now my problem is how I can make my output file to have the same name of the original file but add a -e value at the back?